# insert multiple duplicate rows in a same table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of amenities in which data is inserted one by one for each property and now I want to create duplicate of a property but it gives an error.

```
$sql = "insert into property ($column_str) select $column_str from property where pid = $duplicate_id";
```

It works for a single row but when I insert a property id it doesn't work. my other query is

```
$sql = "insert into apartment_amenity (`property_id`,`amenity_id`) SELECT `1495`,`amenity_id` FROM apartment_amenity WHERE `property_id` = 1494"
```

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column '1495' in 'field list'

Comment: Try removing quotes if its an integer field

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes `'` to wrap 1495 instead of tick marks `

Comment: @RaviPrakashAwasthi This depends if  `1495` is a column than it should be in backticks else in single quotes

Comment: @SuperDJ, while your comment is a correct general practise, the error posted by Ravi shows that 1495 is not a column